# ExtJS button handling

Tags: function, extjs, scope, sencha-touch, extend

What is the best way to add a function to a button? ( specfically scoped )

Dirty example:

```
form.Login= function(config){
if ( typeof config !== 'object' ) { config = {}; }



    var tbarBottom = {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: [{
        xtype:'spacer'
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler:function(button,event){
            console.log(this); // ehh... how do I this.reset() from here? 
                              //( "this" is the buttons scope, not the forms scope )

        }]
    }
    config.dockedItems= [tbarBottom];
    form.Login.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);

Ext.extend( form.Login, Ext.form.FormPanel,{

reset: function() {
    this.reset()// I want to call this function
}

});
```

I've seen examples in ExtJs 4 using

```
this.up('form').reset();
```

and I can also

```
this.ownerCt.ownerCt.reset()
```

But both those feel very awkward somehow. ( the .up much less so, though since I am playing with touch , i dont think "up" is an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
{
    text: 'Reset',
    handler:function(button,event){
    console.log(this); // ehh... how do I this.reset() from here? 
                              //( "this" is the buttons scope, not the forms scope )
    },
   scope : this
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this something that can be done in all javascript, or is it something ext implements?

Comment: The scope can be passed to any function like so `yourFuction.call(yourScope, function-Arguments)` . Defining the scope as i have in the code above is Ext Js's way of passing the scope object